# how to handle toogle button on every and each on tableviewcell in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My code is working fine but it works only for a single cell. When i define 5 rows then it works only for the last cell. If I click on 1 cell then value `displayimage`  on last cell only it not display where i am click and which cell i am click how to handle toogle button change image for each and every cell click on button image this code.

```
-(void)changeMapType:(id)sender
{
    //changeimagetype =!changeimagetype;
//    sender.selected = changeimagetype;

    //sender.selected
    changeimagetype =!changeimagetype;
    if(changeimagetype == YES)
    {
        //flagButton=1;
        //[check setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"];
    [mimageButton setImage:onButtonView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
        //flagButton=2;

    onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
    [mimageButton setImage:onButtonView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20);
        mimageButton.tag = 1;
        //mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png”] //forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png”] //forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        onButtonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
        onButtonView.tag = 2;
        onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png”];
        [mimageButton setBackgroundImage:[onButtonView.image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];
        [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
```

Can you help me correcting the code?

Comment: Your question was not clear.. Pls try to improve..

Comment: rajesh in my cell i have create button on runtime and on button i put background image on toggle action for change image on.png and of.png it work but when i scroll my cell my image is disappear from button how to handle for particular button for toggle action

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294981/how-to-togglebutton-hold-all-button-states-for-all-the-table-rows-in-iphone/8355402#8355402

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the tag for the button as the row number of the table. Then check the tag in the button press method and then perform the logic to change image.

```
-(void)changeMapType:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   // Check tag of button
   // Some code
   //Change image after checking
   [button setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: I consider subclassing UITableViewCell with a decent method to refresh it's sell on buttonPressed a more cleaner solution.

Comment: 7kv7 can u explain in detail how to do in code i am confuse on this

Comment: 7kv7 hi try but my table view cell reuseable when i scroll and my image is disappear how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Take an Array, Store the selected buttons tag in the array and while displaying the button in the cellForRowAtIndex method. check out whether the buttons tag is in that array or not. If its there then show your selected button image else unselected buttons image.